# Dagger 2 Dependency Injection not working

Tags: java, android, dependency-injection, dagger-2

I'm very new to Dagger 2 and I'm trying to get [this](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/Dagger/article.html) basic example working with some minor modifications.

This is what I have so far:

**Component class**

```
@Component(modules = {MyModule.class})
public interface MyComponent {
void inject(Object object);
}
```

**Module class**

```
@Module
public class MyModule {

@Provides
@Singleton
public Retrofit getRetrofit(){
  return new Retrofit();
}
}
```

**Static Injector**

```
public class MyStaticInjector {

private static MyComponent di;

public static void inject(Object object){
    if(di == null){
        di = DaggerMyComponent.builder().build();
    }
    di.inject(object);
}
}
```

The problem is that whenever I do

```
MyStaticInjector.inject(this);
```

the annotated fields are still null. I suspect the problem is with the type Object in the interface method. In the example, there's an Activity instead. But I need to use DI in classes that are not activities.

Can anyone help me? Thank you.

Comment: `Object` has no `@Inject` annotated fields. Thus the injection works just fine; it has nothing to inject. You will have to use your actual classes instead of `Object`, so that the code can be generated and fields can be injected.

Comment: I see... then is there any way to make a generic injector method? Or do I have overload the method inject in the interface for each of the injection class?

Comment: Dagger generates source code at *compile time*. If it does not know about the class, it cannot create code for it. You should read some more tutorials and try to learn more about dagger. Especially have a look at constructor injection.

Comment: Thank you, that was it. I'm used to DI at runtime with Spring or JSF so this is new to me. I'll take a look at more tutorials for sure. If you write an actual answer, I'll accept it. Thank you again.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Object` has no `@Inject` annotated fields. Thus the injection works just fine—it just has nothing to inject.
You will have to use your actual classes with `inject(MyClass)` instead of `Object`, so that the code can be generated and fields can be injected.

Dagger generates source code at *compile time*. If it does not know about the actual class, it cannot create code for it.

Comment: Specifically, see "A note about covariance" in https://google.github.io/dagger/api/latest/dagger/Component.html